# Why the size of /var/lib/docker/vfs is much larger than "docker system df"

Tags: docker

I ran the following commands to check the usage of docker:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib/docker
92K     /var/lib/docker/network
16K     /var/lib/docker/plugins
52K     /var/lib/docker/volumes
58G     /var/lib/docker/vfs
340K    /var/lib/docker/buildkit
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/runtimes
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/trust
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/containers
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/tmp
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/swarm
5.4M    /var/lib/docker/image
58G     /var/lib/docker

$ du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib/docker/vfs
58G /var/lib/docker/vfs/dir
58G /var/lib/docker/vfs
```

But when I ran

```
docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          6         0         6.33GB    6.33GB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

So the size of `/var/lib/docker/vfs` is much larger. Is it possible to further reduce it? Note that I have no running containers or local volumes, etc. I don't want to delete the existing images as I still need them.